# URLClassLoader, "hot-swapping" jar files and ClassFormatError - weird behavior

Tags: java, jar, urlclassloader

**Rewritten from scratch @ Friday, 25 May, about 16:00 GMT**

*(Code is cleaner now, bug can be reproduced and the question is more clear)*

**Original problem:** I'm writing a server app that's required to accept files from clients over the net and process them with certain classes, which are loaded from locally stored .jar-files via URLClassLoader. Almost everything works correctly, but those jar-files are hot-swapped (without restarting the server app) from time to time to apply hotfixes, and if we're unlucky enough to update .jar-file at the same time class from it is being loaded, `ClassFormatError` is thrown, with remarks about "truncated class" or "excess bytes at the end". That's to be expected, but the whole application becomes unstable and starts to behave weird after that - those `ClassFormatError` exceptions *keep happening* when we try to load the class again from the same jar that was updated, even though we use new instance of URLClassLoader and it happens in different app thread.

The app is running and compiled on Debian Squeeze 6.0.3/Java 1.4.2, migration is not within my power.

Here's a simple code that mimics app behavior and roughly describes the problem:

1) Classes for main app and per-client threads:

```
package BugTest;

public class BugTest 
{
  //This is a stub of "client" class, which is created upon every connection in real app
  public static class clientThread extends Thread
    {
    private JarLoader j = null;
    public void run()
      {
        try 
          {
          j = new JarLoader("1.jar","SamplePlugin.MyMyPlugin","SampleFileName");
          j.start();
          }
        catch(Exception e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }

  //Main server thread; for test purposes we'll simply spawn new clients twice a second.
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    BugTest bugTest = new BugTest();
    long counter = 0;        
    while(counter < 500)
        {
        clientThread My = null;
        try
            {
            System.out.print(counter+") "); counter++;
            My = new clientThread();
            My.start();
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) JarLoader - a wrapper for loading classes from .jar, extends Thread. Here we load a class which implements a certain interface a:

```
package BugTest;

import JarPlugin.IJarPlugin;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class JarLoader extends Thread
{
  private String jarDirectory = "jar/";
  private IJarPlugin Jar;
  private String incomingFile = null;

  public JarLoader(String JarFile, String JarClass, String File) 
         throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
    File myjarfile = new File(jarDirectory);
    myjarfile=new File(myjarfile,JarFile);
    if (!myjarfile.exists())
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Jar File Not Found!");
    URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myjarfile.toURL()});
    Class JarLoadedClass =ucl.loadClass(JarClass);
    // ^^ The aforementioned ClassFormatError happens at that line ^^
    Jar = (IJarPlugin) JarLoadedClass.newInstance();
    this.setDaemon(false);
    incomingFile = File
    }

  public void run()
    {
    Jar.SetLogFile("log-plug.txt");
    Jar.StartPlugin("123",incomingFile);
    }
}
```

3) IJarPlugin - a simple interface for pluggable .jars:

```
package JarPlugin;

public interface IJarPlugin 
{
  public void StartPlugin(String Id, String File);
  public void SetLogFile(String LogFile);
}
```

4) the actual plugin(s):

```
package SamplePlugin;
import JarPlugin.IJarPlugin;

public class MyMyPlugin implements IJarPlugin
{
   public void SetLogFile(String File)
    {
    System.out.print("This is the first plugin: ");
    }
  public void StartPlugin(String Id, String File)
    {
    System.out.println("SUCCESS!!! Id: "+Id+",File: "+File);
    }
}
```

To reproduce the bug, we need to compile a few different .jars using same class name, whose only difference is number in "This is the Nth plugin: ". Then start the main application, and then rapidly replace the loaded plugin file named "1.jar" with other .jars, and back, mimicing the hotswap.  Again, `ClassFormatError` is to be expected at some point, but it keeps happening even when the jar is completely copied (and is NOT corrupt in any way), effectively killing any client threads which try to load that file; the only way to get out from this cycle is to replace the plugin with another one. Seems really weird.

**The actual cause:**

It all became sort of clear once I simplified my code even more and got rid of `clientThread` class, simply instancing and starting the `JarLoader` inside the `while` loop in `main`. When `ClassFormatError` was thrown, it not just printed the stack trace out, but actually crashed the whole JVM (exit with code 1). The reason is not as obvious as it seems now (it wasn't for me, at least): `ClassFormatError` extends `Error`, not `Exception`. Hence it passes through `catch(Exception E)` and the JVM exits because of uncaught exception/error, BUT since I spawned thread which caused error from another spawned (client) thread, only that thread crashed. I guess it's because of the way Linux handles Java threads, but I'm not sure.

**The (makeshift) solution:**

Once uncaught error cause became clear, I tried to catch it inside the "clientThread". It sort of worked (I removed the stacktrace printout and printed my own message), but the main problem was still present: the `ClassFormatError`, even though caught properly, kept happening until I replace or remove the .jar in question. So I took a wild guess that some sort of caching might be a culprit, and forced URLClassLoader reference invalidation and Garbage Collection by adding this to clientThread `try` block:

```
catch(Error e)
  {
  System.out.println("Aw, an error happened.");
  j=null;
  System.gc();
  }
```

Surprisingly, it seems to work! Now error only happens once, and then file class just loads normally, as it should. But since I just made an assumption, but not understood a real cause, I'm still worried - it works now, but there's no guarantee that it will work later, inside a much more complicated code.

So, could anyone with deeper understanding of Java enlighten me on what's the real cause, or at least try to give a direction? Maybe it's some known bug, or even expected behavior, but it's already way too complicated for me to understand on my own - I'm still a novice. And can I really rely on forcing GC?

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling the dynamic Jars with?

Comment: With the same 1.4.2 I use for running/compiling the server.

Comment: :(. One more thing: Are these jars being compiled on the server or transferred to it?

Comment: I'm currently testing and compiling all of those on the same machine; in the future they are supposed to be transferred over FTP. Yeah, I'd be glad if file corruption were an issue, but I even checked with diff - files are copied normally :(

Comment: Time to check the bug database and see if it's a possible old bug.

Comment: Nothing related to this in 1.4.2 in the bug database that I can find.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I can hardly believe I found some bug not known before. Could you (or someone else) try and reproduce it, if you have free time?.. Maybe it's not a java bug, but something like filesystem issue, though it's less likely.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. I can't find a bug. I assume something in the urlclassloader would have been found so I was leaning to it being some issue we aren't seeing an not a java bug. Sorry for my failure to clarify what I meant.

Comment: It's more likely that I screwed up while answering you, my English is not good enough :3 I understood you couldn't find a bug in java bug database, and hence I think it's almost impossible for this to be some bug in java "core" modules; that's why I thought that issue may be related to my OS rather then java, and asked if someone could reproduce a same behavior. I'll try to find a different machine and test things there tomorrow, but maybe someone encountered this already and knows what causes this...

Comment: Is changing jar file and loading classes synchronized in any way? Looks like you are rewriting jar file while it is opened and a class is being read. I would recommend to write new far file under some new name, and inform the server to use that new name.

Comment: No, it's not synchronized - and no, unfortunately I don't think this is a case. I don't care if class loading fails while I'm replacing jar-file, there's nothing I can do about it. But that exception keeps occurring over and over for clients that are connected after I replaced the file, even if all the other "jar"-threads finished their work (Client-thread currently waits for jar-thread to exit, so I know when that happens). It seems my description was a bit misleading, changing it now.

Comment: Yeah, renaming files is the most reasonable fallback-option, but the whole hotswap is meant for hotfixing problems in those jar-files, and changing their names would require rewriting config file,  sometimes changing lots of records, so I'd prefer to find a way to get it working like it's now instead. But thank you for a suggestion.

Comment: it's not clear to me.  are you creating a new JarLoader for each jar file, or are you attempting to load new classes from a JarLoader already initialized with a different version of the jar?

Comment: I'm creating new JarLoader (and new urlclassloader) each time client passes me a file via net, not just for each jar file. I tried to make it so that JarLoaders does not interact with each other in any way. That's why when I replace jar-file and new client connects, I expect newly created JarLoader to read replaced jar-file and load my changed class from it, but it gets me an exception.

Comment: Can you post more of your ServerThread and not the puesdo code?

Comment: Yeah, I can, but it seems irrelevant to me, since "j" isn't started nor assigned anywhere else, and since this ServerThread class takes care of exchange protocol, it's kind of huge. I'll try to reproduce the error "in a nutshell" without any excess code in the next 12 hours or so, and will post thr rest of code if I don't succeed.

Comment: Took me "a bit" longer, but at least the whole thing is sort of clear now. Yet I'm still very confused about the real cause...